# pandas.to_csv not displaying floating point values to 2-digits after the decimal place

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing two columns.

```
sample_data = {
    'item': numpy.array(['item1', 'item1', 'item3'], dtype='str'),
    'weight': numpy.array([140.00, 3.00, 90.50], dtype='float64')
}

df = pandas.DataFrame(sample_data)

df.to_csv('filepath')
```

For some reason, when I convert this dataset to a csv file, the file shows:

### item    weight

### item1     140

### item2    3

### item3    90.5

As you can see, instead of 140.00 (item1's row), it shows "140".  How can I get 140.00?

Answer (score 2):

[`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) accept optional argument `float_format`, please try following, replace

```
df.to_csv('filepath')
```

using

```
df.to_csv('filepath',float_format="%.2f")
```

If you know more about formatting strings, read [`printf-style` String Formatting in python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)

Comment: Hello, Daweo.  I tried, but this does not work.  The csv file still does not show 2 digits after the decimal place.

Comment: @BasirMiah I checked my code and it does gives me 2 digits after `.`. What version of `pandas` and what version of `numpy` are you using?

Comment: I am using Pandas version 1.2.4 and Numpy version 1.20.1 (on Jupyter Notebook)

Comment: I just updated Pandas to version 1.3.3 and updated Numpy to version 1.21.2, but it's still not working

Comment: @BasirMiah I used pandas 0.25.3 and numpy 1.18.1, so that code should work as intended on your (newer) setup. I am unable to say why it did not.